# MagicalRecord in method saveWithBlock doesn't find existing entities with MR_FindFirstByAttribute - Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, import, magicalrecord

I'm trying to import entities with this block

```
 MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock({   (moc: NSManagedObjectContext!) in                

      //parsing inquiries
      for (index: String, jsonInquiry: JSON) in json["data"]["inquiries"] {

           var idInquiry =  jsonInquiry["id_inquiry"].int! 
           var inquiry: Inquiry

           //trying to find existing entity
           if let existingInquiry = Inquiry.MR_findFirstByAttribute("id", withValue: idInquiry, inContext: moc) as? Inquiry {
                inquiry = existingInquiry
                println("fetching existing inquiry: \(idInquiry)")
            } else {
                inquiry = Inquiry.MR_createInContext(moc) as! Inquiry
                println("creating new inquiry: \(idInquiry)")
            }
            ...
       }
  }
```

> Only first entity is found as **existing**, others are **created as new**

But when I preFetch all entities at once with:

```
 MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock({  (moc: NSManagedObjectContext!) in

      //preFetch all entities        
      var existingInquiries = [Int:Inquiry]()
      for item in Inquiry.MR_findAllInContext(moc) {
           if let existingItem = item as? Inquiry {
                existingInquiries[ existingItem.id ] = existingItem
           }
      }

      //parsing inquiries
      for (index: String, jsonInquiry: JSON) in json["data"]["inquiries"] {
           ....     
           var idInquiry =  jsonInquiry["id_inquiry"].int! 
           var inquiry: Inquiry

           if let existingInquiry = existingInquiries[idInquiry] {
                inquiry = existingInquiry
                    println("fetching existing inquiry: \(idInquiry)")
                } else {
                    inquiry = Inquiry.MR_createInContext(moc) as! Inquiry
                    println("fetching new inquiry: \(idInquiry)")
                }
          }
          ....
   }
```

> all entities are found as **existing**

Can someone find my mistake or bug? maybe Im missing something basic. 
I'm struggling with this for hours

Thanks

I use XCODE Version 6.3 (6D570) and Swift 1.2

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake
a had this code in my loop - it should be one level up :)

```
for inquiry in existingInquiries.values {
       if !contains(importedInquiries, inquiry) {
                inquiry.MR_deleteInContext(moc)
       }
}
```